# How to mock connectivity in bloc unit-tests?

Tags: unit-testing, flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm using this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity) and I have a following connectivity in a bloc

```
Connectivity _connectivity = Connectivity();
StreamSubscription _connectivityStreamSubscription;

ConnectivityBloc() {
    _connectivityStreamSubscription = _connectivity.onConnectivityChanged.listen((connectivityResult) {
      if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.wifi) {
        add(ConnectivityEventConnectEvent());
      } else {
        add(ConnectivityEventDisconnectEvent());
      }
    });
  }
```

I'm trying to test the bloc, however I'm struggling to mock the StreamSubscription in unit tests. So how can we mock StreamSubscription in bloc_test?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out I didn't pass the instance of Connectivity to bloc.

```
ConnectivityBloc(this._connectivity) {
```

I have mocked the Connectivity with Mockito.

```
class MockConnectivity extends Mock implements Connectivity {}
```

and then I could just pass the Stream with ConnectivityResult I wanted

```
when(mockConnectivity.onConnectivityChanged).thenAnswer(
      (_) => Stream<ConnectivityResult>.fromIterable([ConnectivityResult.mobile, ConnectivityResult.wifi]));
```